# View not visibly changing in Region of Second Window

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a Prism application using v7.0.0396 and I have recently added a second window that opens when the user needs to sign in. This second window is held in a separate module. When the window opens, it should load in the ‘SignIn’ view and if the user needs to create an account, they click the ‘Create Account’ button, which will request navigation to the ‘CreateAccount’ view, in said window.

However, currently I can get it to load the ‘SignIn’ view, but it doesn’t navigate properly to the ‘CreateAccount’ view. I have got the viewmodels of each of these views, to have the INavigationAware interface and I can see the navigating from and to works as expected, but the view in the window doesn’t visibly change.
I noticed at first that even though the module is loaded, the region ‘AuthenticateRegion’ is not added to the regionmanager’s list of regions. Therefore, in the Module.cs file I add the region like so:

```
var region = new SingleActiveRegion {RegionManager = _regionManager};
_regionManager.Regions.Add(RegionNames.AuthenticateRegion, region);
```

Then underneath that I register the views to the region:

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.AuthenticateRegion, typeof(SignIn));
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.AuthenticateRegion, typeof(CreateAccount));
```

In ‘SignInViewModel’, I have the command for navigating to the ‘CreateAccount’ view and use the ‘RequestNavigate’ function:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.AuthenticateRegion, typeof(CreateAccount).FullName);
```

In the AuthenticateWindow.xaml file I have a content control for the views:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.AuthenticateRegion}" />
```

In my experience, this should be enough to work, but it doesn’t show the new view in the dialog window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to dispatch the `RequestNavigate` call to the thread of the second window?

Comment: I hadn't, but I've been trying it now like so: 
`
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.AuthenticateRegion, typeof(CreateAccount).FullName);
                });
`
But I'm still getting the same thing

Comment: more like `otherWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke( ... );`...